# Correct Aspect Ratio and Scaling in iFrame

Tags: iframe, scaling

I am using HTML/CSS to generate a PDF letter (using puppeteer).
I need the positions on the letter to be absolute (in in/mm), however I want to provide a preview for the user as well as HTML while they setup the template.

For that, I want the sizes inside of the document (which is shown in an iframe) still to be e.g. 30mm, however the iframe itself should be scaled so that it fits on the screen (or in my case in the column). How can I achieve this?

Comment: 30mm on what sized screen? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: the screen doesn't matter. I need to use mm or in as units, because I will use this stylesheet as a print (print to pdf) stylesheet. However, I want to use the same stylesheet for preview (to not needing to invoke the pdf generator while writing the styles).
The iframe content will have a fixed width of 210mm x 297mm, however the actual space I am having on the screen for displaying the preview changes based on the browser width (I have two column layout. on one side there's the textbox holding the template, on the other side there is the preview)